# Ansible not pulling git repo

Tags: github, yaml, ansible, git-clone

I'm trying to pull github repo using ansible, but it's giving me following error.

`stderr: fatal: destination path '/var/www/server-ip' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

`msg: fatal: destination path '/var/www/server-ip' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Here is what I've done so far.

`- name: Pull sources from GitHub
  git:
    repo: "{{ item.github_repo }}"
    version: "{{ item.github_branch }}"
    dest: "{{ WEB_ROOT }}/{{ item.server_name }}"
    key_file: "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa"
    force: yes
    recursive: no
  when: item.get('state', 'link') == 'link'
  with_items: VIRTUAL_HOSTS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message already made it plain: the path you are cloning to is not an empty directory. Use another path or delete that directory.